# Misplaced QED symbol with \qedhere inside align* environment

Tags: amsthm

I have an `align*` environment finishing a proof. The environment has three columns. I tried to place the QED symbol using `\qedhere`,  but the symbol collides with the right column. Is this a bug, or should I proceed in an other way? Any hint toward a solution?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
The $\qedsymbol$ is misplaced.
\begin{align*}
A &= B\\
  &= C & = D\qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example of misplaced qed symbol]

I have Texlive 2016, `amsmath 2016/03/10 v2.15b` and `amsthm 2015/03/04 v2.20.2`.

Comment: Why do you need the second `&` in the second equation? Just remove it.

Comment: Bug. `:-(` I checked with all TeX Live distributions up to 2012 and it's the same. Add a `&` in the second line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's undoubtedly a bug in `amsthm`; I checked with all TeX Live versions from 2012 on and it's exactly the same.

Workaround: add `&` somewhere in the affected line: for instance

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
The $\qedsymbol$ is misplaced.
\begin{align*}
A &= B \\
  &= C && = D\qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Depending on what the column is for you might need

```
  &= C & = D & \qedhere
```

(this will provide right alignment for the `=D` part).

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug. An `align` environment expects an `&` between columns of equations, and this is missing in the example. In fact, If there are no further equations to align with the `=D`, the last row should probably be `&=C=D\qedhere`.

Comment: @Dan The `&` is there. The `=D` could be a side condition. While I'd prefer left alignment for side conditions, others may think differently.

Comment: Thanks @egreg for your insights. And right the `=D` is a side comment (in my original example, that I may have oversimplified, there were parentheses around this `=D`).

Comment: @egreg In a line like `&=C &=D` `align` sees the second `&` as a separator between two equations and sees the `=D` as the LEFT side of a second equation (which it surely isn't). Adding or deleting an `&` makes more sense to me than the given example (side condition or not). Since that also makes `\qedhere` work, I still don't see this as a bug.

Comment: @Dan Bug or “undocumented feature”: pretty much the same.

Comment: Isn't it well-known that *k* alignment  groups require 2k – 1 `&`?