# How can a tombstone be put flush right in an environment with tags?

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsthm

I know that, if a theorem's proof ends with a displayed maths environment of a type such as `align*` or `align`, then, in order to get the QED tombstone placed on that environment's last line (rather than on a following line on its own), `\qedhere` must be put in that environment.

However, if that environment contains at least one tag, the tombstone is placed too far to the left. How can I get the tombstone placed flush right? (Adding a `&` or `\hfill` is to no avail.) MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm} % for \proof & \qedhere
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{thm} Theorem-statement.
\begin{proof}
\begin{align*}
a&=b\tag{by some earlier result}\\
&=c\\
&=d\qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is, in my opinion, abusing `\tag`, which is for setting a key for later reference, not for descriptions.

Comment: Anyway, I seem to recall that `\qedhere` does not behave in tagged/numbered alignments. For instance, if you use `align` instead of `align`, the number of the third line disappears.

Comment: @egreg So what do you recommend for typesetting text "descriptions" at ends of lines in display mode? And should they be set flush right or close to the equation?

Comment: I'd make them part of the alignment: closer to it, not flush right. With `alignat*` if `align*` uses too much space.

Answer (score 1):

The `\qedhere` command issued in a numbered or tagged environment doesn't really work (I think it's related to other misfeatures of `\qedhere` like in [Misplaced QED symbol with \qedhere inside align* environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334000/misplaced-qed-symbol-with-qedhere-inside-align-environment)).

Here's a hack:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm} % for \proof & \qedhere

\usepackage{showframe} % just for showing the bounding box

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\altqedhere}{%
  \ifmeasuring@\else\sbox0{\popQED}\fi
  \tag*{\qedsymbol}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
Theorem-statement.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
\begin{align*}
a&=b\tag{by some earlier result}\\
&=c\\
&=d\qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
\begin{align*}
a&=b\tag{by some earlier result}\\
&=c\\
&=d\altqedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Note that `proof` should be *outside* the `thm` environment.

[image]

With `\popQED` inside an unused box, we make `amsthm` into thinking the tombstone has already been used.