# End of proof box is not shown

Tags: theorems, proof-package

When I use the `proof` environment, the output does not show the tombstone   `informs3` class.
The class can be download [here](https://pubsonline.informs.org/authorportal/latex-style-files) by selecting `INFORMS Journal on Computing Style Files`.

I tired the recommendations posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334000/misplaced-qed-symbol-with-qedhere-inside-align-environment) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2274/problem-with-qedhere). If I use a regular document class, it works, but it does not properly work in `informs3` class.

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[ijoc,nonblindrev]{informs3} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,amsthm,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
here is the proof.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also tried to add the symbol manually, but still did not work

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\altqedhere}{%
  \ifmeasuring@\else\sbox0{\popQED}\fi
  \tag*{\qedsymbol}%
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `informs3` class defines its own `proof` environment without any tombstone symbol. You can add

```
\renewcommand{\endproof}{\strut\hfill\Halmos\endTrivlist\addvspace{0pt}}
```

to your preamble to add the tombstone (which is the `\Halmos` command) to the end of the `proof` environment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you mind letting me know the source of the information? When I face with an ```informs3``` based issue, I really don't know where to look for the answer.

Comment: I looked into the ``informs3.cls`` file and searched for a ``proof`` environment. Luckily I found quickly the definition! My answer here is just a slight modification of the definition of ``\endproof`` in the source file. It's good to keep in mind that whatever LaTeX does, it's coded somewhere in some source files, so all of the information is always coded somewhere. Sometimes it can be hard to read, but it can also be a good way to learn!